# I May Have Horns, But I Am Not the Devil

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, language

*A big credit to @frodoskywalker for my riddle. Although the user did not write this riddle, one of their answers on this site served an inspiration. I will not show the particular answer, however, in order to not spoil the riddle, but I fully encourage you to visit the user's profile and check out their content.*

---

> > **Riddle me this:**
>
> *I am heavier than a boulder, 
>  For which I will never flow; 
>  But I am lighter than the feather, 
>  Of a raven or a crow. 
>  
>  I can be found in heated weather, 
>  Where not often, it would snow. 
>  My arm may look like driest leather, 
>  Spraying water with a blow.* 
>  
>  ***What am I?***

*Comparing mine arm to a tree, 
 Forsooth, it will be not a branch. 
 May thou solve for what I could be? 
 Try! sabotage not thy chance! 
 
 A man was so hight after me; 
 His real name was seldom spoken. 
 May thou solve for whom he could be? 
 His poem might have thee heartbroken.*

---

My previous riddle proved too easy, so I have added the "Shakespeare vibe" in the hint above so as to make the riddle harder, hence why I included the `wordplay` and `language` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you an

> Elephant

I am heavier than a boulder, 
For which I will never flow;

> Elephants are very heavy.

But I am lighter than the feather, 
Of a raven or a crow.

> Maybe the shadow of which is used in a known puzzle(what is the same size as an elephant but weighs nothing). OR, as Jafe suggested in the comments, it could refer to the paler color of an elephant.

I can be found in heated weather, 
Where not often, it would snow.

> In Asia and Africa

My arm may look like driest leather, 
Spraying water with a blow.

> They have trunks that spray water.

The title

> The horns maybe the tusks.

Comparing mine arm to a tree, 
Forsooth, it will be not a branch.

> An elephants legs are massive they may be as large as a tree's trunk.

May thou solve for what I could be? 
Try! sabotage not thy chance!

> I answered it.

A man was so hight after me; 
His real name was seldom spoken.

> There was [a man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Merrick) who had a disease and people called him "Elephant Man". (From EightAndAHalfTails)

May thou solve for whom he could be? 
His poem might have thee heartbroken.

> ???

LOL, it seems like I answer most of your puzzles whether I get them right or not :D

Comment: "Lighter as a feather" could mean rot13(yvtugre pbybhe, abg jrvtug).

Comment: Hahah, 'tis true! You do answer my puzzles a lot, and most of the time you get the answer correct (to which I might forget to accept the answer when it is). In fact, this answer is also correct, and @jafe had the correct reasoning. However, can you work out the meaning of the hint? I can write down the meaning of the archaic terms if you are unsure of their definition. (I will upvote in an hour.) :D

Comment: You answered the first part of the hint correct :)

Comment: "A man was so hight after me; His real name was seldom spoken." Refers to [this man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Merrick). "Hight" is an archaic word meaning "named"

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails, thanks I will add that in :D

Comment: I see you have added the second part in, and that is correct! Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$